# Possible to convert this OOP clock to a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the below class in my otherwise pure function project. It is the only part that is OOP, and I and would like to make a function that isn't instantiated if possible.

I use it like so

```
const timer = new Clock(1);
await timer.start();
const coolDownTimer = new Clock(2);
const globalTimer = new Clock(3);
await globalTimer.start();
```

**Question**

Making the clock OOP was the only way I could think of, so I am wondering weather it would have been possible without making an instance of the Clock class?

```
const Clock = function (checkInterval) {
  let offset;
  let clock;
  let interval;

  // initialize
  reset();

  function start() {
    if (!interval) {
      offset = Date.now();
      interval = setInterval(update, checkInterval);
    };
  };

  function update() {
    clock += delta();
  };

  function delta() {
    const now = Date.now();
    const d = now - offset;
    offset = now;
    return d;
  };

  function stop() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
    };
  };

  function reset() {
    clock = 0;
  };

  function read() {
    return clock;
  };

  // public API
  this.start = start;
  this.stop = stop;
  this.reset = reset;
  this.read = read;
};

module.exports = Clock;
```

Comment: Would `return {start, stop, reset, read}` resolve your issue?

Comment: Sure; call the clock function, and the function would return its "internal" functions (noting that there is no "Clock class" here).

Comment: NB: [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) has a specific meaning that is different from what you seem to mean with it.

Comment: What's wrong with OOP? And notice it's still OOP when you don't use `new` but call a function that returns a new object with methods.

Comment: `await timer.start();` does not make sense. Your `start` method does not return a promise.

Comment: Why are you doing this? There's no problem with mixing functional and OO code in the same application. You do it all the time when you use built-in methods like `forEach()`.

Comment: This isn't even really OOP, since your methods don't use `this`. It's basically an object containing closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the `Clock` function return a simple object containing the state of the clock. Then replace the methods with ordinary functions that take one of these objects as a parameter, and access the properties.

You'll need to export all the functions that should be callable by clients. In my example below I export them all, you may find it more appropriate to keep some of them internal.

```
function Clock(checkInterval) {
    let self = {
        offset: null,
        clock: null,
        interval: checkInterval
    };
    clock_reset(self);
    return self;
}

function clock_start(clock) {
    if (!clock.interval) {
        clock.offset = Date.now();
        clock.interval = setInterval(() => clock_update(clock), clock.interval);
    };
};

function clock_update(clock) {
    clock.clock += clock_delta(clock);
};

function clock_delta(clock) {
    const now = Date.now();
    const d = now - clock.offset;
    clock.offset = now;
    return d;
};

function clock_stop(clock) {
    if (clock.interval) {
        clearInterval(clock.interval);
        clock.interval = null;
    };
};

function clock_reset(clock) {
    clock.clock = 0;
};

function clock_read(clock) {
    return clock.clock;
};

module.exports = {
    Clock,
    clock_start,
    clock_update,
    clock_delta,
    clock_stop,
    clock_reset,
    clock_read
};
```

Comment: Yuck. But exactly what was asked for…

Comment: Agreed. Basically, this is how you would do it in a language like C, without OOP or closures.